# Change the value of a low frequency column to a desired value

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr, tidyverse

In my `data` below, I want to replace any value in a column (*excluding the first column*) that occurs less than two times (ex. `'greek'` in column `L1`, and `'german'` in column `L2`) to `"others"`.

I have tried the following, but don't get the desired output. Is there a short and efficient way to do this in R?

```
data <- data.frame(study=c('a','a','b','c','c','d'),
L1= c('arabic','turkish','greek','arabic','turkish','turkish'),
L2= c(rep('english',5),'german'))

# I tried the following without success:

dd[-1] <- lapply(names(dd)[-1], function(i) ifelse(table(dd[[i]]) < 2,"others",dd[[i]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forcats` has specific function for this:

```
dd = data
dd[-1] = lapply(dd[-1], forcats::fct_lump_min, min = 2, other_level = "others")
dd
#  study      L1      L2
# 1     a  arabic english
# 2     a turkish english
# 3     b  others english
# 4     c  arabic english
# 5     c turkish english
# 6     d turkish  others
```

Your approach fails because `ifelse()` returns a vector the same length as the test, which in your case is the `table`, but the way you are using it you are assigning to the whole column so it needs to return something the same length as the whole column.

We can fix it like this:

```
dd[-1] <- lapply(names(dd)[-1], function(i) {
  tt = table(dd[[i]])
  drop = names(tt)[tt <= 2]
  ifelse(dd[[i]] %in% drop, "others", dd[[i]])
})
```